# Multiple replacements when query-replacing

Tags: query-replace

I have a piece of code like this:

```python
def convert(tir_expr: tir.expr.PrimExpr) -> expr.Expr:
    if isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Add):
        return convert_Add(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Sub):
        return convert_Sub(tir_expr)
```

And I have a lot of convert_XXX cases, and I'd like to get the following result, i.e. repeatedly replacing all XXX with some YYY:

```python
def convert(tir_expr: tir.expr.PrimExpr) -> expr.Expr:
    if isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Add):
        return convert_Add(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Sub):
        return convert_Sub(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Mul):
        return convert_Mul(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Div):
        return convert_Div(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.IntImm):
        return convert_IntImm(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.FloatImm):
        return convert_FloatImm(tir_expr)
    elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.StringImm):
        return convert_StringImm(tir_expr)
```

I don't know how to achieve what I want and how to search an answer for that. Any tips?

Comment: Do you actually want to auto-generate text analogous to `elif isinstance(tir_expr, tir.expr.Sub):
        return convert_Sub(tir_expr)`?